# Set-up python logging on a separate file - Foundry Code Repository

Tags: python, palantir-foundry, python-logging, foundry-code-repositories

de-facto standard in Foundry is log additional messages inside the main pyspark logger, as by [foundry - pyspark logging doc](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/pyspark-logging/#code-repositories).

> Logging output appears in both your output dataset's log files, and in your build's driver logs (Dataset -> Details -> Files -> Log Files, and Builds -> Build -> Job status logs; select "Driver logs", respectively).

This works fine, but being written directly in the driver log, tend to be complex in querying/reading.

Is it possible, and what would be the right way to set-up a separate python logging handler, in order to write on a separate user-defined log file?

Comment: This currently is not supported, were doing some feature work to improve the experience with logs. What would your intent here be?

Comment: Querying the driver log after the job is quite complex because the actual python logs are hidden in nested JSON structures.

Comment: As mentioned by @nicornk, main driver log is quite crowded. I'd like a separate file in order to have strict user-defined logs, easily accessible by build monitoring users

Comment: @CheTesta got it, we hear you! A better experience is currently in the works, but I don't know when it will be GA.

Comment: One workaround while waiting for GA would be to write a simple transform that reads the driver log and parses information on certain level/certain prefix/from certain logger to a separate dataset.

Comment: The beta of the log viewer just arrived on our stack, nice improvement!

Comment: @fmsf any news on the subject?

Comment: You can ask your internal support to enable the beta of the log viewer in your stack if it's not available yet.